# Function Recursion in shell

Tags: bash

I'd like to know why this recursive function in shell works properly:

```
exp ( )
    {
        local result
        #local op1="$1"
        #echo $2
        if [[ $2 -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo 1
            return
        fi 
        tmp=$(( $2 - 1 ))
        local result1=$(exp $1 $tmp )
        result=$(( $result1 * $1 ))
        echo $result
    }
    exp 3 4
```

But when touching $2 in any way, for example like this:

```
exp ( )
    {
        local result
        echo $2
        if [[ $2 -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo 1
            return
        fi 
        tmp=$(( $2 - 1 ))
        local result1=$(exp $1 $tmp )
        result=$(( $result1 * $1 ))
        echo $result
    }
    exp 3 4
```

It fails with:

```
4
foo.sh: line 15: 0
1 * 3 : syntax error in expression (error token is "1 * 3 ")
foo.sh: line 15: 2
3 * 3 : syntax error in expression (error token is "3 * 3 ")
9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that you touch `$2`, it's that you `echo` stuff. Your function is, as you say, recursive. This means that it will process its own output. As soon as you have it printing out anything other than a single return number (which is what you expect), it will break.

Specifically, your function will do this:

```
    tmp=$(( $2 - 1 ))
    local result1=$(exp $1 $tmp )
    result=$(( $result1 * $1 ))
    echo $result
```

This works fine when the output of `exp $1 $tmp`, which is saved as `result1` is just a single number. However, when you echo something else, the output of `exp` is no longer a single number so the simple math operations you do will break.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `exp 3 0`, save it as `result1` and ask yourself if `$(( $result1 * $1 ))` makes sense now.

The function expects itself to print one number. You make it print (`echo`) two numbers. At some point `result1` contains two numbers and then `result=$(( $result1 * $1 ))` is syntactically wrong.